# pymongo ImportError although it is installed

Tags: python, pip, pymongo

I am trying to get pymongo running on our linux server, however something fails, yet I dont know what.

I have the same setup running on my local machine (OsX)

I installed pymongo using pip, as suggested:

```
$ sudo pip install pymongo

Downloading/unpacking pymongo
Downloading pymongo-3.1.tar.gz (462kB): 462kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pymongo/setup.py) egg_info for package pymongo

Installing collected packages: pymongo
Running setup.py install for pymongo
building 'bson._cbson' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/time64.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/encoding_helpers.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbson.so
building 'pymongo._cmessage' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pymongo/_cmessagemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessage.so

Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
```

So you think pymongo is installed, yet it is not recognized by Python:

```
$ python -c "import pymongo"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

Also in python itself:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Nov  3 2015, 14:21:40) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
>>> exit()
```

Does anyone have any clue? I did not have this issue on my mac

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
```

Comment: Do you have two version of Python installed on the same machine ?

Comment: yes I do, 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: I had something similar on my machine, I think you installed pymongo for version 3.4. By following Dex instructions (`python setup.py install`) you explicitely called the `setup.py` script for 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install it from source:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git pymongo
$ cd pymongo/
$ python setup.py install
```

Don't forget its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

Comment: thanks so much! that worked like a charm, any idea why the pip install failed? (just for personal learning)

Comment: Installation issues are not subject of the source code.The dependencies are properly defined inside the `setup.py` of the specific package using the 'install_requires' configuration so maybe that's why.

Comment: It seems you initially installed pymongo for version 3.4. By following @Dex instructions you now installed it for Python 2.7 as well.

Comment: But macOS doesn't have apt-get, I wonder what's the corresponding package name of "build-essential" for homebrew?